# Can I verify that an input field is masked or shows the text?

Tags: java, selenium

Using Java and webdriver, I'm trying to setup a test to verify that the password I type is masked. With my tool, we have a setting that allows you to have the password masked or to show the text. I was wondering if anyone has ever verified something like this with Selenium.

Here is what I want to check
Setting OFF - type into the input field and verify that text is displayed
Setting ON - type into the input field and verify that my input is masked

I believe the browser handles masking, so I'm not sure if I can do this test or not. The element for the input field does not have any attributes about masking.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `type` property if the input, if it's `text` the text is not masked, if it's `password` it is masked.

Answer (score 0):

So suppose you have your input field as following

```
<input id="pw" type="password" blah>
```

You can check if the field is masked by doing

```
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pwd"));
if (password.getAttribute("type") == "password"){
    // if it is, do something
}else {
    // not masked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(My GitHub pages are taking their sweet time updating) Here is the HTML you can try out:

```
<input type="text" id="regular" />
<input type="password" id="masked" />
```

And using the [Getting Started with Selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) framework, your test would look something like this to validate to make sure the field is indeed masking.

```
@Config(browser = Browser.CHROME, url = "http://ddavison.github.io/tests/maskedtextbox.htm")
public class MaskedText extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void testMasked() {
        // validate that the regular text box is not masked.
        setText         (By.id("regular"), "Unmasked")
        .validateText   (By.id("regular"), "Unmasked") // validate that this isn't masked.

        .setText        (By.id("masked"),  "Masked")
        .validateTextNot(By.id("masked"),  "Masked")   // validate that the text is not "Masked" if it is, then it isn't masking correctly.
        ;
    }
}
```

When `validateTextNot` is called, it will get the text of that field, and it will return `******` and `Masked` does not `.equal` that.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println (password.getAttribute("type").equals("password"));

Apply that code.
It will check the attribute that your type = password or not.
If equals to Password than return true if not than return false.